# refind bootup menu Doesn't show up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, refind

Device: HP ProBook 4540S

I installed refind for multi-boot purposes with refind-install, and also set the boot order

But there is no refind menu when I boot up

I see a grub2 menu where the fyedos option isn't there.

It's just ubuntu and UEFI firmware setup option.

But if I F9>Boot from efi file>Acpi>EFI I get both os option alongside refind.
\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi
Clicking it gives the refind menu.

Is there any way I can make refind menu start by default instead of grub so that I can select my needed osin peace (i just switched from windows to Linux, only know how to copy-paste commands :-) )

Answer (score 0):

First, try running the `refind-mkdefault` script that comes with rEFInd. If you installed rEFInd via a Debian package, typing `sudo refind-mkdefault` in a Terminal window should do the trick. If you installed in some other way, you'll need to find the script. (I comes in the rEFInd `.zip` file, for instance.)

Second, if that doesn't work, then you've probably got a buggy UEFI that's forgetting its boot order. I Googled your computer's name, and found reviews of it from 2012, and UEFIs from that era were notoriously buggy. You may want to read [this page of the rEFInd documentation](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html) to learn about how to deal with such problems. In particular, the [last section,](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html#fallback) on using the `fbx64.efi` program (renamed as `EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi` on the ESP), may help work around the problem. In brief, you may need to rely on the UEFI's fallback boot loader (`EFI\BOOT\bootx64.efi`), which is run when other boot loaders can't be found or are invalid. This may require you to rename any other boot loaders that *are* currently running, though. Unfortunately, it's hard to provide precise instructions that are guaranteed to work, since there's so much variability in how those old UEFIs are broken, as well as your own software/OS installations.